# Why am I getting #NA error on doing Vlookup?

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'All Users w Associations'!$A$2:$D$714,3,0),0)

I am trying to add the full name from the first spreadsheet to the second, using the username as the constant value.  I’d love to know what I’m doing incorrectly

Sheet 1 (All Users w Associations)

[image]

Sheet 2- Vlookupformula

[image]

Comment: Are you definitely getting an NA error? What do you get if you remove the iferror() wrapper? Are they definitely identical?  Try putting `=A2=All Users w Associations'!$A$2` somewhere and seeing if you get TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Do you mean you're referencing a separate excel file entirely? Because there's not reference to the filepath in your formula so it's bound not to work..

Comment: I am trying to reference Sheet1 in my formula that is named 'All Users w Associations'..maybe that's not correct way of referencing?

Comment: I tried putting ='All Users w Associations'!$A$2 in a cell and the correct name is returned ABBOTTC

Comment: If I remove the if error(), I get #NA.

Answer (score 0):

There were either spaces before or after the user names. When I got rid of the extra spaces this worked.